# How to Format numbers using Google Embed API - Decimal placement limit - Whole numbers

Tags: api, google-analytics, formatting, numbers, embed

I would like to format numbers returned via Google's Embed API, mostly controlling decimal count, and comma placement for numbers 1000+.

I found this documentation on NumberFormat for Google Charts, as well as the following link to the Embed ref guide:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformatter
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/reference

The syntax is different for Embed, so the Google Charts number formatting doesn't seem to apply.

Here's my Embed syntax...I'm assuming there's some way to add options for number formatting, similar to what I placed in the options param below:

```
var avgSessionDuration = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
reportType: 'ga',
query: {
  'metrics': 'ga:avgSessionDuration',
  'start-date': '30daysAgo',
  'end-date': 'yesterday',
},
chart: {
  type: 'TABLE',
  container: 'avgSessionDuration',
  options: {
    'NumberFormat': {
      pattern: '$###,###'
    }
  }
}
```

});

I feel like I've read every word of every Embed reference material, and can't find this anywhere, but it seems unlikely there's not a solution out of the box.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure this out, im having this exact issue as well :(

Comment: Also having this issue. Anyone figured it out?

Comment: Bringing in avgTimeOnPage and it's just integer data.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the single quotes around 'NumberFormat'.  I don't believe those are required and they may be causing the problem.

Comment: Hey Mate,

I have the exact same issue as the OP, removing the quotes doesn't work you still end up with numbers like 12345.2344645766578545 Any other ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: To be honest, my answer was based on my limited experience with google charts.  I had a thought though - you would never apply a number format to a table, you would apply it to a specific column or specific cells for that table so it makes sense that the numberFormat isn't working here.  Whatever the answer is will likely be applied in a different manner.  With Google charts you can apply formatting after you build you datatable but before drawing the chart.   I know this doesn't give a solution but maybe it will help point others in a direction to finding one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply makes sense, i'll keep giving it a bash :)